# MATLAB - making rows/colums that are not in a list, all 0

Tags: matlab, matrix

if i have a matrix, say:

```
A = [ 0 2 4 6 
      2 0 5 7
      4 5 0 3
      6 7 3 0 ]
```

and i want to make all elements in the rows and columns in a list equal to zero i can use:

```
del_list = [2 4]
A(del_list,:) = 0
A(:,del_list) = 0
```

which gives me:

```
A = [ 0 0 4 0 
      0 0 0 0
      4 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 ]
```

but how can i make `del_list` into a `keep_list` and only keep those rows and columns that are in the list, so using my example before

```
keep_list = [2 4]
<do something>

A = [ 0 0 0 0 
      0 0 0 7
      0 0 0 0
      0 7 0 0 ]
```

the way i have worked out to do it is like this:

```
keep_list = [2 4]
n = size(A,1)
for ii = 1:n
   if ~any(keep_list==ii)
       A(ii,:) = 0;
       A(:,ii) = 0;
   end
 end
```

is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new matrix and just put in the values you want

```
B=zeros(size(A));
B(keep_list,:)=A(keep_list,:);
B(:,keep_list)=A(:,keep_list);
```

Yes you will have 2 matrices not 1, which will use extra memory, but that wont be a problem most of the time unless your matrices are large, you can always remove `A` once you've made `B`.

Comment: haha, of course, sorry, i should have thought of that! thanks, i will accept the answer in 7 mins when it will let me..

Answer (score 1):

You can try making the del_list from the keep_list using Matlab's set subtraction command and use the same technique as in your original post.

```
keep_list = [2 4];
all_indices = 1:size(A,1);
del_list = setdiff(all_indices, keep_list);
A(del_list,:) = 0;
A(:,del_list) = 0;
```

Comment: interesting, how computationally expensive is setdiff()? do you think it would be better to create a new matrix (as in the other answer) and populate that or to use this setdiff method?

Comment: I'm not sure about the implementation of setdiff, but I think it would be an n^2 algorithm for brute force (check every element of all_indices against every element in keep_list), or if it sorted first, then n + cost of the sort. I think the answer in the previous post would be faster but requires more memory. The previous method requires memory for 2 n^2 matrices and one array of size up to n, this one for only 1 n^2 matrix, plus 3 arrays of size up to n.

Comment: The previous method requires computation time of n^2 for the looping for populating the second matrix, this one requires computation time of n^2 for the looping for zeroing out the matrix, plus the time for the setdiff (nlogn at fastest)